# Update a trained CNN with more images

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to understand conceptually how I could update an already trained CNN. So as I receive new labelled images (possibly one at a time), the network would retain what it has learned previously, but also readjust its weights with new incoming images.

I would appreciate any thoughts on this - I'm reading up the topic and have not found any answers on this. Thank you

Comment: You can retrain the network with old and new data. If you only train with new data most likely it will yield catastrophic forgetting.

Comment: @Frightera So I would not be able to update a network slowly as more data is received? For example, if I wanted to classify images of cats and dogs, and I get images one at a time, could I not train the network initially on the first few images. Then as more images come in, train it on those (without having to retrain on the old data). The reason being that if there is a lot of old data, the time to train may take incredibly long.

Comment: Probably your network will yield to forget old data distribution.